# Executing API of a AWS Lambda function multiple times throws "message": "Endpoint request timed out". How to resolve this problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Lambda Specs: Python Version - 3.7 || Memory - 10240MB (10GB)

The Synchronous API timeout limit is 30 seconds. My code executes for 4 seconds. The below code is a sample one that sleeps for 4 seconds.
I'm using EFS mounted in Ubuntu for storing the packages as the limit of lambda deployment is 250MB.

```
import time
import json
import os
import sys 
sys.path.append("/mnt/access")
import math
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sqlalchemy
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    time.sleep(4)
```

1. This is a simple code integrated with API Gateway. It works fine when executed one or two times but when executed more than 10 times it runs into a timeout error.
2. I tried to use Provisioned Concurrency but it is so expensive. What to do to make it work all the time? Any Alternatives?

Comment: Take a look at CloudWatch Logs and view the log output for the Lambda function. It is likely that it is hitting the default timeout of 3 seconds, and is therefore not returning to API Gateway. The log file will show whether this is the situation.

Comment: The lambda timeout is 15mins. The code runs for 4 seconds. The API works fine when I execute it but when I execute the same API 20 times in 1 second most of the calls throw endpoint timeout error as the API timeout limit is 30 second. When I execute it for 20 time does API work parallelly or they work one after the other?

Comment: It might be needing to create extra Lambda containers to handle the spike in usage. See: [AWS Lambda execution environment - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html)

Comment: I'm using EFS for getting the packages. When I execute it without EFS, the above sleep code is working fine after calling it multiple times. But when I call it multiple times with EFS it is throwing an error after the 5th API call. My Packages size is close to 700MB. I cant import it in the Lambda as the limit of Lambda is 250MB, I suppose. Do you think EFS can cause problems when executing it multiple times? What are the other ways to import packages other than EFS or uploading directly to the Lambda?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're essentially loading 700MB from EFS to RAM before the lambda_handler starts.

Turn on XRay tracing as well and see if that shows a very slow init time.

It's not that EFS is causing problems so much that EFS might be slow enough that getting the 700mb into RAM on a new container lambda might be taking a while.

Answer (score 0):

What is the AWS Lambda function timeout set at?

It sounds like the lambda function timeout is set too low.[image]

https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home - open the function and set the timeout under basic settings.

Comment: The timeout is 15mins. So I guess that's not the problem. It's not that my API doesn't work. It works fine but when I call the API multiple times in 1 second it throws the timeout error. Are the API calls dependent on each other? For eg: I call the API 20 times in 1 second, the 20th time will execute only after it's previously calls gets completed.

Comment: Is there some kind of write lock on whatever you're mounting from EFS? Like a sqlitedb or something?